# Transitioning between pageloads

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

I want to have transition effects between pageloads like slide, rotate, fade, etc.  I'm trying to accomplish this with the following code, but it's not working.  Any ideas?

```
$("asp:HyperLink.smoothlink").click(function (e) {
    $("body").addclass("fadeout");

    setTimeOut(function() {
        window.location = e.currentTarget.attributes['data-url'].value;
    },1000);
}
```

CSS

```
.fadeout
{
    opacity:0;
    transition :opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: first of all you have a typo, it's `setTimeout()` , not `setTimeOut()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand you are trying add an animation to your current page when you click on a specific link. It seems that you are working in a .NET environment and I'm not too familiar with its WebControls, however couple of errors stand out:

- You are not using proper selector string - `asp:HyperLink.smoothlink`. Try using `a.smoothlink` instead.
- JavaScript is case-sensitive so `addclass` and 'setTimeOut`are causing an error. Try using 'addClass` and `setTimeout` instead.
- You also might need to use the `href` attribute instead `data-url`, but that really depends on what is the .Net control generating.

Here is a working example of what i think you are trying to do:

HTML:

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" class="smoothlink">example link</a>
```

CSS:

```
.fadeout {
    opacity:0;
    transition :opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition-opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a.smoothlink").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("body").addClass("fadeout");
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location =  $(event.currentTarget).attr('href');
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```